# Error in type referencing mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a node application with mongodb using mongoose ODM. I am getting an error while type referencing schemas that reside in different files.

I have following code in user.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Trip = require('./trip');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    salt: String,
    hash: String,
    emailAddress: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    trips: [{Type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Trip'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

userSchema has a type reference to tripSchema.

Code in my trip.js file is:

```
    var tripSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      location: String,
      arrivalDate: Date,
      departureDate: Date,
      type: String});

   module.exports = mongoose.model('Trip', tripSchema);
```

When I run the application, I am getting following error:

```
    /usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:360
    throw new TypeError('Undefined type at `' + path +
          ^
TypeError: Undefined type at `trip.ref`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType       (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:360:11)
    at Schema.path (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:303:29)
    at Schema.add (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:217:12)
    at Schema.add (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:212:14)
    at new Schema (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:73:10)
    at Function.Schema.interpretAsType (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:345:44)
    at Schema.path (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:303:29)
    at Schema.add (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:217:12)
    at new Schema (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:73:10)
    at Mongoose.Schema (/usr/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:53:12)
```

I am unable to figure out the reason of error. If both the schemas are in same file, code is running fine. But when I seperate out schemas in two different files, I am getting above error. How can I resolve this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am getting the same error and even tough I have check the answer to your issue is not my case. Once I find a solution I will post it here for other people to find a solution when they get to this page.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a typo in your userSchema. You've put

```
trips: [{Type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Trip'}]
```

But it should be

```
trips: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Trip'}]
```

`Type` should be lowercase `type`

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing it out! :) I wasted my whole day trying to figure out the reason of the error.